# At the restaurant

Tags: grammar, articles

> *At the restaurant*.

Why the heading is at the restaurant even though the readers don't know the particular restaurant?
Shouldn't the heading be at a restaurant?

https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/skills/reading/a1-reading/restaurant

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink this.  "At a Restaurant" is also a good title for that page.

This however is a typical style for English textbooks.  The textbook asks you to pretend to be in places to practice speaking English.  You pretend that there is a town with a post office, clothes store, cafe and restaurant (etc).

You then practice the English you could use "at the post office" or "at the restaurant".  It is all part of the pretending and role-play.

Comment: In the street, on the bus, in the train, at the station. We will end up in the grave.